# How to convert my CSV file to Excel file in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, excel, react-admin

I am new to react-admin and I would like to have the possibility to export my CSV file to Excel.

```
import {FieldGuesser, ListGuesser, InputGuesser} from "@api-platform/admin";
import React from "react";
import jsonExport from 'jsonexport/dist';
import { ReferenceInput, SelectInput, Filter, downloadCSV } from 'react-admin';

const orderExporter = orders => {
  const ordersForExport = orders.map(order => {
    return {
      "Name": order.name,
      "Email": order.clientEmail,
      "Code": order.programCode,
    };
  });
  jsonExport(ordersForExport, {}, (err, csv) => {
    downloadCSV(csv, 'orders');
  });
};


export const OrderList = props => (
  <ListGuesser {...props} exporter={orderExporter} filters={<OrderFilter/>}>
    <FieldGuesser label="Statut" source={"status"}/>
    <FieldGuesser label="Name" source={"name"}/>
  </ListGuesser>
);
```

Do I have to create a new component with a special library? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would have just made this a comment but don't have the rep on this account yet. Have you checked out the SheetJS library? https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

You should be able to use this in your orderExporter function instead of the downloadCSV function. I have used it for importing files and it was relatively straightforward, but I haven't used it for exporting just yet. This demo project has an example: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/master/demos/react/sheetjs.js